# Password field is not working while dragging mouse using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue.I have a password filed with an eye icon.When user will click on this eye icon the whatever password has typed will displayed as text and mouse up again it will displayed as password.In my case it happening like this but when user is dragging mouse up/down after click on eye icon the typed password is showing as text which should not happen.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span style="position:absolute; right:5px; margin-top:6px;"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success"ng-mousedown="hideShowPassword();" ng-mouseup="hideShowPassword();" ><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button></span>
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Password :</span>
<input type="{{inputType}}" name="itemname" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="password" >
</div>
```

the related controller code is given below.

```
$scope.inputType="password";
     $scope.hideShowPassword=function(){
         if($scope.inputType=='password'){
             $scope.inputType="text";
         }else{
             $scope.inputType="password";
         }
     }
```

Here my problem is suppose user clicked on eye icon,the password displayed as text and same time user dragged this up/down by keeping mouse press at that time password also displaying as text which i don't need.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you show us the link from where you tried this. Also try debugging your code and check if there are any errors or not.

Comment: There is no need to typed from any link for this requirement.Simple set input type dynamically.But problem is occurring while dragging and angular has no drag event.Did you have any solution ?

Comment: i haven't much worked on angular JS part, but it seems the issue must be related with some js errors.

Comment: @nadeem : There is no error here.